# Why do velocity templates require a name?

Tags: java, velocity

I am refactoring some Java code that generates some HTML using many raw `StringBuilder.append` operations. In order to be more expressive and easier to read/maintain I'd like to use a simple templating system like Apache Velocity instead. In the code snippet below, `MyClass` takes a string, which holds the contents of the template (loaded from a file), and instantiates a corresponding `org.apache.velocity.Template` object. Now, I understand that in many applications there could be multiple templates and it might be handy to be able to look them up by name, but in my application there is just one and I never need to look it up because I have a reference to it. My questions are then:

1. Why do I need to define a name for each template when I parse it? (e.g. to satisfy the signature of `org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeServices.parse`)
2. Am I missing something here / doing something horribly wrong?

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       private static final String TEMPLATE_NAME = "dummy name";
       private Template template;

       public MyClass(String templateString) throws ParseException {
           Velocity.init();
           loadTemplate(templateString);       
       }

       private void loadTemplate(String templateString) throws ParseException {    
           RuntimeServices runtimeServices = RuntimeSingleton.getRuntimeServices();
           SimpleNode templateContent = runtimeServices.parse(templateString, TEMPLATE_NAME);

           template = createTemplate(runtimeServices, templateContent);
       }

       private Template createTemplate(RuntimeServices runtimeServices, SimpleNode templateContent) {
           Template template = new Template();
           template.setRuntimeServices(runtimeServices);
           template.setData(templateContent);
           template.initDocument();
           return template;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Because the system is not designed for a single template. If you can reuse your's (because you saved a reference), what is the problem?

Comment: It's not so much a "problem" in that I can't make it work, but rather it "feels wrong". If a `templateName` is truly not essential then why isn't there another `parse` method that does not require it as a parameter? In other words, it seems like `parse` is doing more than 1 thing (parsing but also registering/saving), so I would think there must be a good reason otherwise these should be separated, right?

Comment: Who says it is truly not essential? It is essential in every use case but your's.

Comment: It's not needed in order to parse the template; that's what I mean. I didn't say it wasn't useful.